# UITextView - how to disable highlighting?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I disabled editing, but how do I disable the selection interface from popping up? I don't want the user to be able to highlight text, or copy it etc.

It is important to preserve vertical scrolling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
textView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Ok then if you need to preserve scrolling, then create a scrollView, set it as an outlet and add the textview on it.

Then in viewWillAppear set the textview's height:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
  self.descriptionTextView.text = @""; // set some text to determine the total height
  self.descriptionTextView.frame = CGRectMake(self.descriptionTextView.frame.origin.x,
                                              self.descriptionTextView.frame.origin.y,
                                              self.descriptionTextView.frame.size.width,
                                              self.descriptionTextView.contentSize.height);
  self.descriptionTextView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
  //next set new content size for scroll view
  self.descriptionScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.descriptionScrollView.frame.size.width,
                                                        self.descriptionTextView.frame.origin.y + self.descriptionTextView.frame.size.height);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't that also prevent scrolling? Though the question doesn't state how _much_ text is present...

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4**, **Xcode 10**

Make sure you set the delegate to YourViewController

```
yourTextView.delegate = yourViewControllerInstance
```

Then this will disable highlighting, enable tapping links and allow scrolling

```
extension YourViewController: UITextViewDelegate {

    func textViewDidChangeSelection(_ textView: UITextView) {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }

}
```